# How do I click a menu item from the application menu using Appium and Python on Windows?

Tags: python-appium, winappdriver

I am working on automating UI-tests for an application and have trouble with menu items on Windows. Fwiw, I have it working on Mac for the sister-application.
I am using Appium from Python.

I can find the menu tree using Inspect.exe, click the top-level menu, which then opens the dropdown, and in here I find the menu item, I want to click, but WinAppDriver fails with this error:
`{"status":105,"value":{"error":"element not interactable","message":"An element command could not be completed because the element is not pointer- or keyboard interactable."}}`

The below python reproduces the problem.

```py
import time
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

app_exe_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Phase One\\Capture One 12\\CaptureOne.exe"
menu_name = "Select"
menu_item_name = "First"
switch_window = True
# app_exe_path = "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe"
# menu_name = "File"
# menu_item_name = "Open..."
# switch_window = False


class ClickApplicationMenuItem(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_click_application_menu_item(self):
        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor="http://localhost:4723",
            desired_capabilities={"app": app_exe_path},
        )
        if switch_window:
            time.sleep(5) # non-optimal code for the sake of a simple repro
            handles = driver.window_handles
            driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
        menu = driver.find_element_by_name(menu_name)
        menu.click() # fails in the Notepad case
        item = menu.find_element_by_name(menu_item_name)
        item.click() # fails in the CaptureOne case


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Any advice on how to click the menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for the menu item (I am keeping the `menu.click()` since that works for the application, I am testing):

```py
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   actions = ActionChains(driver)
   actions.click(item)
   actions.perform()
```

Comment: So you didn't need those coordinates after all? That's even better :-).

Comment: Exactly :-)
What puzzles me a little is why the WebElement.click method reports that the very same element isn't clickable. Perhaps some day someone will dig into that and maybe file an issue...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to find those elements, I assume you have access to their properties.
A simple workaround could be to click the elements coordinates instead of clicking the element itself. Usually, clicking coordinates is a bad idea, but since you get the coordinates from the element itself, I see no problem here.

Try something like this:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_name(menu_name)
driver.Mouse.Click(menu.coordinates)
item = menu.find_element_by_name(menu_item_name)
driver.Mouse.Click(item.coordinates)
```

I did get a warning that the mouse functionality is obsolete and that the `Actions` or `ActionBuilder` class should be used. You could explore those options as well, but I found a issue that got closed on March 2018 on winappdriver's github page, about that `Actions` class. It's unclear why it's closed. You can find an alternative way of clicking the coordinates there to.

Resources:
[`Actions` issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/285)

Comment: Thanks, that is an elegant proposal :-) I will try it out the next time I am working on that project - which is on the 21st

Comment: Great! Be sure to come back here to tell me how it worked out, I haven't implemented this solution so not sure if it will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right track @PixelPlex !
I've just posted my own answer :-)